# Sockets client problem after copy-paste from Microsoft C# working example

Tags: c#, sockets

I've tried the Microsoft C# dotNET sockets examples and I've got both the sync and async client examples working with a remote server on my intranet. My problem is that when I copy-paste the async client code into my application the send() doesn't get through to the server. There are no reported errors and the reported number of bytes sent matches the requested length. The server reports the connect as expected, so I'm stumped as to what the problem is and, with no reported errors how to debug it.

As the code is lifted off the MS example I'm not sure what to post up that's helpful but here's the source for the send call and the callback. Inspection shows cmdBytes[] is the expected 3 bytes in length and in the callback bytesSent is 3.

```
private static ManualResetEvent sendDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
.... code to generate 3 cmdBytes[]
   sendDone.Reset();
   // Begin sending the data to the remote device.  
   mySocket.BeginSend(cmdBytes, 0, cmdBytes.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), mySocket);
   sendDone.WaitOne();
....
   private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   {
      // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
      Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
      // Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
      int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);        // debugger reports bytesSent is 3
      // Signal that all bytes have been sent.  
      sendDone.Set();
   }
```

Update, further investigation reveals that the problem is with connect() and probably nothing to do with this code.

Comment: put server receiving part of the code, i think you sent bytes to server but you do not properly handle received bytes

Comment: I'm very familiar with these samples and very experience debugging network issues.  I'm almost sure that the data was sent since are not getting any exceptions.  If you did not get a connection you would of gotten an exception and the client would be null and would of gotten an exception in the send method.  So the error is either in the server or you connected to a different server than the one you are using.  You could open putty instead of the server to see if the message was really received.

Comment: Thanks for the comments as they are pointing me in the right direction, which is that there's nothing wrong with the send! I've got as far as seeing the socket disconnecting spontaneously right after connecting! Should I edit this post or close  it and start a new one?